# How to keep an alarm program alive

Tags: android

I am writing an alarm program for android and am very happy with it so far. But I have a big concern about how to make sure it keeps running constantly. I.e. I don't want the OS to kill it to free up memory (I'd like the OS to kill other apps first) and I want to ensure that the program starts up again if the user powers down and up again. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: You make sure that it **doesn't** run constantly. You're not supposed to. Not even with a service. There is a reason Android is trying to kill your process, you shouldn't try to work around it. If you're working on an alarm program, better take a look at [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) instead.